# Why does the constant term of the antiderivative disappear when deriving the Laplace transformation of f(t) = t

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to derive the Laplace transformation

\begin{align}
f(t)&=t\\
F(s)&=\int_0^\infty t\cdot e^{-st}\;\mathrm{d}t.\\
\end{align}

Using the partial integration rule

\begin{align}
\int f'g = \left[fg\right]_0^\infty - \int fg',
\end{align}

with $f' = e^{-st}, f = \tfrac{-1}{s}e^{-st} + C$ and $g = t, g' =1$. In every derivation I come across the constant $C$ is gone.

My question is: where does the constant $C$ go? What step am I missing?

Comment: We ignore $+C$ when taking definite integrals.

Comment: Is this because we then get $[... + C]_a^b$ on both sides and it cancels out? Do I understand this correctly? If you post this as an answer (instead of a comment to the original question) I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: $F(s) = \int_0^\infty t e^{-st}dt$ doesn't depend on $C$, that's quite obvious, no ?

Comment: For an integral over a bounded interval, you can take any primitive of $f'$. But when you're integrating over $[0,+\infty)$, you need to take a primitive such that $\lim_{R\to+\infty} f(R)g(R)$ and $\lim_{R\to+\infty} \int_0^R f(t)g'(t)\,dt$ exist. That severely restricts the admissible values of the integration constant.

Comment: If you could post this answer in the top comment I can mark it as the best answer, because Sean's answer doesnt mention that we're dealing with indefinite integrals here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating definite integrals, we ignore constants of integration. We do this because we'd be writing $C-C$ which is zero. As $C$ is independent of $x$ or whatever independent variable is chosen, we will always end up getting zero in the evaluation step.